# Mobile screen readers doesn't "click" over offscreen or inferior `z-index` items in HTML documents

Tags: android, html, ios, css, screen-readers

am i wrong or mobile screen readers can't "click" over offscreen items? If i have an item displaced from the main screen like so:

```
.button {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
}
```

double tapping over it when focused doesn't seems to work, nor Android neither IOS. In fact items positioned using lower `z-index` values behind others with a superior `z-index` value seems to be unreachable too. For example:

```
.below-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

.top-layer {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

If i try to "tap" on the `below-button` having the `top-layer` over it, i can only "tap" on the  `top-layer`. It seems that the screen reader can only interact with the highest `z-index` value items.

Any help on this topic would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

What you have stated is the whole purpose of having a `z-index`.

As per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index),

> The z-index property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

In other words, an element with a higher `z-index` will always have a pointer events precedence than an element covered by it with a lower `z-index` in case the have the same `position` property. Otherwise, a `position: absolute` element takes precedence over a `position: relative` element and so on.

Comment: thanks for your answer nashcheez, i have the `z-index` concept clear in my mind, but what i try to understand is "why can i "click" on elements below others in desktop versions of screen readers while i can't do the same using mobile screen readers, and also why can't i "click" over offscreen positioned items using mobile devices screen readers while i perfectly can do it on the desktop versions?"